# Thread safety and RSACryptoServiceProvider returned by X509Certificate2.PublicKey

Tags: .net, cryptography, rsacryptoserviceprovider

`RSACryptoServiceProvider` is documented as potentially not thread safe. Unfortunately, it uses internal call for `EncryptKey` so I can not analyse the code to verify it.  So is it known whether it is actually thread safe?

I am asking because I had problems with thread safety in `System.Security.Cryptography` at least once (`MD5`).

My question is very similar to [Mitigating RsaCryptoServiceProvider thread safety issues on a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140764/mitigating-rsacryptoserviceprovider-thread-safety-issues-on-a-web-server), however that question was not really answered (experiment on whether something fails under high load does not guarantee thread safety).

Comment: If it's not documented to be thread safe, I'd assume that it is not. Microsoft can change the implementation depending on framework and OS version. Some of them might be thread safe, some might not.

Comment: OK, so you think I should find a way to re-create `RSACryptoServiceProvider` returned by `X509Certificate`?